# Is there a way to combine Sort and Filter a table

Tags: syntax-error, powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula

I'm relatively new to Power Apps and I am trying to sort and filter my table at the same time. Sadly for me it seems to be not working.

```
Sort(
        Projects;
        Projectnumber;
        SortOrder.Descending
    )
Filter(
       Projects;
        StartsWith(
            Projectnumber;
            SearchProject.Text
        ) || StartsWith(
            Designation;
            SearchProject.Text
        )
    )
```

These are the function I am trying to combine. Maybe using `SortByColumns` would be better.

I have already looked for some answers online but all the options there wont work for some reason on my Power App.

```
SortByColumns(
    Filter(
        Projects;
        StartsWith(
            Projectnumber;
            SearchProject.Text
        ) || StartsWith(
            Designation;
            SearchProject.Text
        )
   );
    Projectnumber;
    If(varSortDirection = SortOrder.Descending; SortOrder.Ascending; SortOrder.Descending)
)
```

This was one option that should work but it gives me an Error with Invalid Argument.

Did they change the Syntax of it over time or why wont this work?

Comment: Please expand on "not working".  Do you get an error or an unexpected result.

Comment: Both functions above work just fine when they stand alone, but when im trying to put them togehter I get an Error with Invalid Arguments. Even when I'm putting them directly next to each other, I get an Error.

Comment: "together" and "next to each other" are equally unhelpful descriptions. What is the actual code that causes the error, and what is the actual error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this formula:

```
Sort(
    Filter(
        Projects;
        StartsWith(Projectnumber; SearchProject.Text) ||
        StartsWith(Designation; SearchProject.Text)
    );
    Projectnumber;
    SortOrder.Descending
)
```

It should work for you.

---

`SortByColumns` function works with **internal name** of columns as available in data source. If you are using SharePoint online list as data source, you can get the internal name of your column by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

Assuming internal name of your column is `Projectnumber`, you can use formula like below:

```
SortByColumns(
    Filter(
        Projects;
        StartsWith(Projectnumber; SearchProject.Text) ||
        StartsWith(Designation; SearchProject.Text)
    );
    "Projectnumber";
    SortOrder.Descending
)
```

Notice, column name is wrapped within double quotes like `"Projectnumber"`.